# How to use tifffile and psdtags to create multi-channel tiff files

Tags: python, tiff, psd

I have two tif files, one of which is a CMYKA channel file, and the other is a single channel file [w1]. I want to merge the w1 channel file into the CMYKA file, but I don't know how to use tifffile and psdtags to generate a new CMYKAw1 channel file

I've tried doing this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
isd = TiffImageSourceData.frombytes(b'Adobe Photoshop Document Data Block\0')

res = TiffImageResources.frombytes(bytes())
res.name = 'temp.tif'
res.psdformat = PsdFormat.BE32BIT

res.blocks.append(
    PsdVersionBlock(PsdResourceId.VERSION_INFO,
                    1,1,'Adobe Photoshop',
                    'Adobe Photoshop 2020',True))
res.blocks.append(
    PsdPascalStringsBlock(PsdResourceId.ALPHA_NAMES_PASCAL,
                    values=["alpha","w1"]))
res.blocks.append(
    PsdPascalStringsBlock(PsdResourceId.ALPHA_NAMES_UNICODE,
                    values=["alpha","w1"]))
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "merging"?

Comment: The following content is from Google Translate, because I don’t understand English, I’m very sorry, the meaning of merging is that I need to get a new tiff file, which contains CMYKA channel and W1 channel, a total of 5 channels, of which CMYKA channel comes from the first tiff file, and W1 channel comes from the second tiff file

Comment: TIFF does not support five channels, so what _end result_ are you trying to achieve? What does the final data look like? And how is that built up from the starting data?

Comment: To be precise, there are actually 7 channels, tiff has 4 channels for CMYK, because it has a transparent channel, there are 5 channels, and then there are two spot color channels, one channel is the varnish layer, and the other channel is the white ink layer. I use it on a UV printer.

Comment: Yes, TIFF consists of data blocks that encode image layers so what do you mean with _merge_? Do you mean "just add another layer to the file", do you mean "mix the colors somehow", do you mean "change the color space and concatenate the image data to create a much bigger image", _what does merge mean_ and please [edit] your post to make it explicit what you're talking about, because just showing code doesn't tell people what you intended to do and thus whether that code even matches your intentions or whether it's something completely different (which happens a lot in people's first posts)

Comment: I want to generate a tiff file with labeled spot color channels like the one in the link below. When opened in photoshop, there are W1 and W2 channels in the channel interface besides CMYK

https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/files/11844519/origin.zip


In addition to CMYK files, the UV printer also needs to add two layers of spot color channels in tiff for printing of varnish and white ink. If the varnish layer and white ink layer cannot be merged or generated through code, then I have to use photoshop to generate it manually.

Comment: That's excellent information but again: [please put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask). I'm not asking for details because "I" need them, I am asking for more details to be put into your post so that _everyone_ can read it and get the details they need to help answer your question, without needing to read through a comment thread. Click [edit] and then rewrite your post such that it covers those "what you're working with", "what you need to do", "what code you wrote to do that", "what you expect that code to result int", "what that code yields instead", and "what debugging you did".